# Java : Removing unwanted characters of an object with clean code

Tags: java, object

I have an object retrieved from a form. It can contains some unwanted characters like "/n". I would like to remove them. I've found a way of doing it but I'm pretty sure it's possible to do it in a cleaner and shorter way?

```
List<Client> clients1 = pc.getClients();
List<Client> clients2 =new ArrayList<Client>();

if (clients1 != null) {
    for (Client tc : clients1) {    
        tc.setClientId(tc.getClientId().replaceAll("\\p{C}", ""));
        tc.setClientName(tc.getClientName().replaceAll("\\p{C}", ""));
        tc.setCallFirstName(tc.getClientFirstName().replaceAll("\\{C}",""));
        clients2.add(tc);
    }
}

pc.setClients(client2)
```

Any suggestions? The point of this question for me is to learn how to make better code.

Comment: Why do you create a new list when you set the replaced strings to the existing `Client`s?

Comment: What do you see as unclean or long in this solution?

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-remove-all-special-characters-of-String-in-java.html

Comment: you can use regex as mentioned in above link

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity they're already using regex.

Comment: hold on. You should let only certain characters to be allowed in form. like ^[a-zA-Z]+$ for first name and client name.

Comment: @kayaman. I thought that it could be done in one line using lamba expression.

Comment: Using an array you can try the following solution: removing-element-from-object-array-with-linq-js


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385947/removing-element-from-object-array-with-linq-js

Comment: @FarazDurrani why? Why can't the OP support other characters in the names? If those names aren't used in situations where chinese, arabic etc. characters would cause problems then why not allow them?

Comment: @daniu I thought it could change the first list

Comment: @jhamon thanks I didn't know this webiste. I'll have a look

Comment: @FarazDurrani huh? Did that question put you under pressure? As for me, I'm chilled ;)

Answer (score 4):

The "clean code" answer would be framed around the [Tell, don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle.

In your case: you are **first** fetching (asking!) some attribute from a Client object, to make changes to that, to re-set the property.

Why not just go and **tell** the Client `tc.normalizeFields()` or something alike?!

Meaning: instead of having *another* class cleaning up fields of the Client class, put all of that code **into** the Client class itself! And have one method that internally works all fields that require "cleaning". So that when fields are added or removed, *other* classes do not need to be changed. The code you are showing needs to be updated each time you add/remove/change your fields.

When your Client class is more of a bean/data thing (that only carries around data, without any specific behavior, aka methods of its own), then you should consider to use a separate `ClientNormalizerService` class that encapsulates this work for you.